# Laravel: How do I access the unique ID of a logged in user and use it in a database query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am making a website for college administration where professors log in and assign marks to the students they are teaching.

There's a table, called ***"IA_Marks"*** in my database:

```
|Student_ID|Subject_Code|Name|Marks1|Marks2|Marks3|Semester|Division|
```

There's also a table called ***"Classroom_Mapper"*** in my database, that helps map a professor to a classroom, with a subject:

```
|Prof_ID|Subject_Code|Semester|Division|
```

---

My Problem:

I wish to fetch the `Subject_Code`, `Semester`,`Division` fields from the ***Classroom_Mapper*** table so that I can use it to fetch the `Student_ID`,`Name`,`Marks1,2,3` from the ***IA_Marks*** table.

To fetch the 3 fields from the ***Classroom_Mapper*** table I will need the `Prof_ID` field, which is **unique** for every professor.

Every professor logs in using his `Prof_ID`.

1. How do I fetch the Prof_ID?
2. When I fetch the Prof_ID, how do I fetch the other 3 fields from ***Classroom_Mapper*** into my controller?

I need get those fields so that I can narrow down the `select` query results on ***IA_Marks***, which currently displays the whole table.

This is my current code: It shows the complete table, instead of just showing the records that are needed:

UserDefinedController.php

```
public function show(){        
        $data = DB::table('iamarks')->get();
        return view('ia',compact('data'));
 }
```

ia.blade.php

```
<table>
        <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>SUBCODE</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>IA1</th>
                <th>IA2</th>
                <th>IA3</th>
                <th>SEMESTER</th>
                <th>DIVISION</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($data as $row)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $row->ID}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->subcode }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->IA1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->IA2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->IA3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->semester }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->division }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </table>
```

---

My idea of solving this problem:
(The syntax is definitely off! But I hope you can see where I'm heading with this.)

```
//Think of this as a pseudo-code
public function show(){
    $Prof_ID = LoggedInUser->Prof_ID;
    $Semester = DB::table('classroom_mapper')->pluck('Semester')->where('Prof_ID','=',$Prof_ID);
    $Division = DB::table('classroom_mapper')->pluck('Division')->where('Prof_ID','=',$Prof_ID);
    $data = DB::table('iamarks')->get()->where('Semester = $Semester' AND 'Division = $Division');
    return view('ia',compact('data'));
}
```

I just can't figure out how to fetch those values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Here's what I did:

```
public function showTable(){
    $sem = DB::table('classroom_mappers')->where('Prof_ID', auth()->user()->PID)->pluck('semester');
    $division = DB::table('classroom_mappers')->where('Prof_ID', auth()->user()->PID)->pluck('division');
    $data = DB::table('iamarks')->where([['semester','=',$sem],['division','=',$division]])->get();
    return view('ia',compact('data'));
}
```

This works, but I have another problem here:
Say the professor teaches two subjects, in two semesters. Then, the `where` clause will return multiple results from the mapper table. I am trying to solve the problem by showing students only from the target semester, and target division, but I'm not quite sure how I can do it, yet.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I fetch the Prof_ID?

Using the [`auth`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-auth) helper or the `Auth` class you can run:

```
Auth::user()->Prof_ID
```

to get the ID of the user. If you are using the `Auth` class, ensure you [`use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) it:

```
use Auth;
```

> When I fetch the Prof_ID, how do I fetch the other 3 fields from Classroom_Mapper into my controller?

You'd setup a relationship between your Professor model as is taught how to in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships). Alternatively you can do a bog-standard [`join`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) with your model to pull the data you need.